# Show boot log at boot instead of boot animation?

Tags: boot, cyanogenmod

I have a Nexus 5 running CyanogenMod 11. Normally, my boot animation looks like this:

[image: http://www.loadthegame.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cyanogen.jpg]

Instead of this, I'd like to have something that simply shows me the contents of `dmesg`, or something else that usefully updates me on the status of what's being loaded and how far along things are.

I'm wondering if there isn't something simpler available. Is there a "developer" boot animation that might report this info? Failing that, what's the best way to get a standard dmesg output or something similar as my boot "animation"?

---

**Note:** I've already looked at Chainfire's **[live logcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.livelogcat&hl=en)**, but it's over two years old. Setting it as my boot animation just glitches my screen and soft-bricks my device, necessitating a reflash. So while that would have been an ideal solution if it worked, it looks like that might be the wrong avenue to pursue.

Comment: No, there isn't a developer boot mode. System integrators get the same boot animation as anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's new version of [[root] LiveBoot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.liveboot) for devices 4.3 and up on the Google Play Store. There is also a thread for it on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/liveboot-t2976189)