# Android Boot Logs Before Logo

Tags: bootloader, kernel, logging

BTW, I am wanting to know what Android Boot Logs come before the Android Boot Logo. I see an Android Boot Logo, and I have to hold the power button, but what does it show in the boot logs in the background before the Android Boot Logo?

**NOTE:** I think I could use the command line to see the last startup log, what command could I use?

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve by taking logs? Boot logo is usually shown by bootloader. And bootloader log is accessible by no simple means. Or are you talking about boot animation?

Comment: I am wanting to be able to take note of the startup logs that are shown by bootloader in the background, yes. And yes, I am talking about the mobile phone & tablet.

Comment: android has no feature for that. you need to connect with PC and run logcat https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225239 or use an app to emulate https://android.stackexchange.com/q/81207

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-take-logs-in-android